# UIImageView with iOS GLES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiimage

I am new to `OpenGL` and am looking for any code snippet for drawing a simple `UIImage` to the screen - exactly as `UIImageView` does.

The Internet is full of code samples like this, but all of them add a little bit of smoothing to the picture, and when (in my code) I add an `OpenGLView` over a `UIImageView`, the user can see this moment. The text on the `UIImage` becomes a tiny bit smoother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an existing solution, you could use the GPUImageView from my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework, coupled with a GPUImagePicture to pull in your UIImage. The code to perform this display would be something like the following:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
GPUImageView *imageView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[stillImageSource addTarget:imageView];
[stillImageSource processImage];
```

The point of this framework is to perform OpenGL ES-based image and video processing, so this is the most rudimentary thing you can do with the framework. Filters and other kinds of image processing operations can be added in a chain from the image to the view.

This OpenGL ES-based image view has three different fill modes which can be set through the `fillMode` property, but by default it will stretch the image to fill the view. You should be able to use this property to match the fill mode of your UIImageView.

You can examine the code for the GPUImageView to see how I take in a texture and display it based on these different fill modes and possible image rotations. Basically, I just use two triangles to establish a rectangle and use a passthrough shader to display a texture within that rectangle, which is pretty much what everyone else does in this case.

The difference in smoothing you see may come from differences in the way that textures are filtered on the GPU vs. how Core Graphics scales down images, if you're placing images within these views that are sized differently than the views they are displayed in.